# I want to enable form fields in php if only username is available otherwise the fields should remain disabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to enable form fields in php if only username is available otherwise the fields should remain disabled.

How can I do this ?

Pls take a look at the [this](http://hannahsclinic.com/salaamforex/registration.php) page.
Can anyone help please.

Code:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="sampleform" id="form1">
                            <input name="uname" type="text" id="uname" class="uname" style="text-transform:lowercase;" />
                            <span class="req">*</span>
                        <input type="submit" name="chkuserid" value="Check User ID availability" id="chkuserid" class="btn" style="width:200px;" />
       <?php              
          $con=mysql_connect("localhost","***","****")or die("Unable to connect");

          mysql_select_db("****_salaam",$con)or die("Invalid");                  
       if(isset($_POST['chkuserid']))
{ 

     $nmu=$_POST['uname'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_reg where unm='$nmu'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
    {

      echo "Username already existing";

   ob_flush();


    }
    else
    {
    echo "Username available";
    }

}
   ?>
```

Comment: Why not post the portions of code that you have narrows the problem down to?  You have tried to debug and narrow down the problem haven't you?

Comment: if you can upload your code its more easy to help you.

Comment: I have added the code..pls check

Comment: You can read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to understand how you can write your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using ajax.

When the user click the checkAvailabilty we send an ajax request to the server. The server will return json with either true or false.

Depending on that we can show that the username is avialble or not.

Similarly you will enable the other fields if the response json from the server is true.

**This is a good tutorial. You can read this for more information
http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/**

**Please dont forget to add a server side validation when the user register's in your website.
Client side validation can't be trusted.**

Answer (score 0):

you gonna use ajax request and on the success  of the request (username available) you need to change the default view state of the fields.

That's simple i guess, are you looking for code

Answer (score 0):

Just run a if else condition in PHP, it will work.

```
if ($username == '$name')
{
your active form 
}

else
{
your disabled form 
}
```

for this you need to fetch the username / id or anything unique to recognize the user.

Answer (score 0):

First you hit your request using ajax and get the information about username.

By default make inputs as

```
 disabled="true"
```

If username is available then you and enable the other inputs. For Ex:

```
document.getElementById('uniqueId').disabled = false;
```